# Flutter add self signed certificate from asset folder

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-http

My server provides a Self Signed certificate when calling its HTTPS API. I have the certificate file in the `asset` folder and referenced its path in `pubspec.yaml` 
I have tried passing the certificate to `SecurityContext` and then using that context to create an `HttpClient`. But the way I'm passing the certificate to `SecurityContext` is not working. Here is the code:

```
Future<ByteData> getFileData(String path) async {
    return await rootBundle.load(path);
}

void initializeHttpClient() async {
    try {
         Future<ByteData> data = getFileData('assets/raw/certificate.crt');
         await data.then((value) {
             var context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
             context.useCertificateChainBytes(value.buffer.asInt8List());
             client = HttpClient(context: context);
         });

    } on Exception catch (exception) {
         print(exception.toString());
    }
}
```

The `SecurityContext` has two methods:
1) `useCertificateChain()` this accepts a file path. But when I give the path of the file in my asset folder ('assets/raw/certificate.crt'). It says file not found.
2) `useCertificateChainBytes()` the above code is using this method. But this also gives me error like (unexpected end of file).

**Solution as of now**

I am bypassing it using `client.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;`.

**but I'd like to make it work with certificate**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what the role of the self-signed certificate is. Based on your work around, I assume that it's a server side certificate that you have installed in the HTTPS server. (It's not a client side certificate that you would like to pass to the server.)

So, what you need to do is to get the Dart `HttpClient` to trust that certificate, which will be passed to it by the server as part of the TLS handshake. (By setting the callback you have made the client trust any certificate, not just your server's.)

To set the trusted certificate use `setTrustedCertificatesBytes` in place of `useCertificateChainBytes` (which you would use if your certificate was a client side one).

You cannot access assets directly as `File`s as they are bundled by the build. You are doing the right thing by loading them and using the `...Bytes` methods. You could improve the readability of your code like this (removing the `then`). Also, note the subtle change to `Uint8List`

```
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/raw/certificate.crt');
SecurityContext context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
client = HttpClient(context: context);
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is working? Because as far as I know it will throw error of file not found exception. @Richard Heap

Comment: I am still using it. If the file you provided is at that path and is of proper format it will work

Comment: yes it is working fine with Flutter native or dart native which is working in dart VM (dart.io) . but it is  not working on Flutter web(dart.html) . we do not have classes that support SecurityContext and SecureSocket class for dart web . does any one have solution for same

Comment: @SANU It would be a huge security hole if a JavaScript program could control which certificates the browser trusted. For testing or internal use you could install the cert - see for example https://peacocksoftware.com/blog/make-chrome-auto-accept-your-self-signed-certificate. In production you'd need to use a properly signed cert.