# Flutter add client certificate to request using http.dart

Tags: flutter, dart, client-certificates, dart-http

I'm trying to load a client certificate to a http.client from the **[http.dart](https://pub.dev/packages/http)** package.

I'v seen multiple answers on how to do it using the **HttpClient** class,
like this answer: [Flutter add self signed certificate from asset folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54110360/6284863), which basicaly suggests to do the following code

```
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/raw/certificate.pfx');
SecurityContext context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
context.useCertificateChainBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
context.usePrivateKeyBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
client = HttpClient(context: context);
```

But I must use the **http.dart** package since i have a function that accepts a `http.client`
something like this

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var httpClient = http.Client();
// i'd like to configure this httpClient to use a specific client certificate

var client = MyClient(httpClient);

....

MyClient (http.Client? httpClient) {
    -- some constructor logic --
}
```

Is there any way to configure a `http.client` to use a client certificate?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove as http and var http = Client();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the `http.Client()` constructor. Instead, construct an `IOClient` (which is a subclass of `Client` as can be used instead). Pass in your `HttpClient`.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/io_client.dart';

void main() async {
  final context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
  // modify context as needed
  final httpClient = HttpClient(context: context);
  final client = IOClient(httpClient);

  await client.get(Uri.parse('https://somewhere.io'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i'm getting an error `Unsupported operation: default SecurityContext getter` running a flutter web app, it seems like dart:io is a support for non-web applications, any workaround?

Comment: what i ended up doing was, adding a condition to check the platform (kIsWeb) and return `http.Client()` in a case of web

Comment: Indeed, but I assumed that you'd be using mobile rather than web, as that might be a security hole to load a client cert from assets on web.

Comment: @Yonatan, how do you check the platform and return dynamic client?

Comment: How did you get around this error ? Unsupported operation: default SecurityContext getter running a flutter web app ? Did it ever work in web ?

Comment: @NothingBox there are several ways to detect the platform, here is an example [How do you detect the host platform from Dart code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50744481/6284863)

Comment: @PranavSawant was not able to get it to work in web

Answer (score 2):

you can use client certificates from a flutter client, thanks to DIO, which use dart.https instead of dart.http with this kind of code,

from my repo : https://github.com/ysimonx/mtls-ssl-generator

```
void getHttp() async {
  Dio dio = new Dio();

  ByteData clientCertificate = await rootBundle.load("assets/clientCrt.pem");
  ByteData privateKey = await rootBundle.load("assets/clientKey.pem");
  String rootCACertificate = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/caCrt.pem");

  dio.httpClientAdapter = IOHttpClientAdapter()
    ..onHttpClientCreate = (_) {
      final SecurityContext context = SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: false);

      context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(utf8.encode(rootCACertificate));
      context.useCertificateChainBytes(clientCertificate.buffer.asUint8List());
      context.usePrivateKeyBytes(privateKey.buffer.asUint8List());
      HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient(context: context);

      httpClient.badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {

        if (cert.pem == rootCACertificate) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      };

      return httpClient;
    };

  final response = await dio.get('https://localhost:3000/');
  print(response);
}
```